# Upgrade 5.56.1 errors

Tags: upgrade

Installed civicrm 5.56.1 as upgrade to 5.54
When tried to set localization got
Warning: Undefined array key "html_type" in /home/mastersu/public_html/wp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Admin/Form/SettingTrait.php on line 298

Warning: Undefined array key "name" in /home/mastersu/public_html/wp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Admin/Form/SettingTrait.php on line 301

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "IntlDateFormatter" not found in /home/mastersu/public_html/wp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/log/php-8.1-strftime.php:65 ...
Site says PHP intl not installed but reviewing PHP setup shows:
[image]

Any suggestions?